# Tree traversal SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data

Anyone, please help me with the SQL query for traversing the tree.
I have a table called `users`, which has the columns `id`, `name` , and `parent`.

Please, help me with a SQL query that can traverse the tree from the desired root.

EDIT
Hi i got this URL that seems to be solved.

[Deeply nested subqueries for traversing trees in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926529/deeply-nested-subqueries-for-traversing-trees-in-mysql)

But i don't have knowledge of JOIN, Thats y i cant construct the query with my table :-(
:-(

Comment: What do you want to get out of it?

Comment: what is the table structure, table data and expected output ? And what have you tried till now ?

Comment: You need to understand JOIN to use SQL.  JOIN is as fundamental to SQL as `foreach` is to PHP.  Try reading fearless leader's [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 3):

MySQL does not support recursive queries.  Most other brands of database support recursive query syntax with the *common table expression* syntax (queries beginning with `WITH`).

To solve tree traversal queries in MySQL, you need to store the data differently so you can query whole trees in one query.  There are several solutions for this:

- Path Enumeration
- Nested Sets
- Closure Table

For details, see:

- [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462)
- [Models for Hierarchical Data with SQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)
- [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/)